# Check string length in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string that is 141 characters in length. Using the following code I have an `if` statement to return a message if the string is greater or less than 140.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);
$message = $xml->xpath("//div[@class='contest']");

if (strlen($message) < 141)
{
   echo "There Are No Contests.";
}
elseif(strlen($message) > 142)
{
   echo "There is One Active Contest.";
}
```

I used var_dump on $message and it shows the string is `[0]=> string(141)`. Here is my problem: When I change the numbers for the `if` statement to `<130` and `>131`, it still returns the first message, although the string is greater than 131.

No matter what number I use less than 141 I always get "There Are No Contests." returned to me.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try the common syntax instead:

```
if (strlen($message)<140) {
    echo "less than 140";
}
else
    if (strlen($message)>140) {
        echo "more than 140";
    }
    else {
        echo "exactly 140";
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

`[0]=> string(141)` means $message is an array so you should do `strlen($message[0]) < 141` ...

Answer (score 4):

`[0]=> string(141)` means that $message is an array, not string, and $message[0] is a string with 141 characters in length.

Answer (score 3):

`$message` is propably not a string at all, but an array. Use `$message[0]` to access the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`$xml->xpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) always return an ***array***, and `strlen` expects a ***string***.

Answer (score 1):

**An XPath solution is to use**:

```
string-length((//div[@class='contest'])[$k])
```

where $k should be substituted by a number.

This evaluates to the string length of the $k-th (in document order) `div` in the XML document that has a `class` attribute with value 'contest'.