# php check string has no space and length greater than limit

Tags: php

I have a website where user can add reviews. Now Issue is some user add very lengthy strings and I'm unable to stop them to do that, like a user added a review:

```
aatdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

Another user put this review:

```
ggvddghjbxvjfuihdfjkljgghkkollkkkkkkļfghjjkjjjjjjjjjjhjbjjxxfdfhgsxvvbdsxvvgssxcxxźvgggfggffccccffghjjjjjjjhfdsxvhjnbdddhugsdhjnnhhjjjjnnjxxssfghjiikjkmjjhgcxsdghjkkkk
```

Here is code:

```
if (isset($_POST['addReview'])) {
    $summary = isset($_POST['summary']) ? trim($_POST['summary']) : '';
```

How I can check input string length and make sure there are no reviews like above and input is only words?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check String Length In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563152/check-string-length-in-php)

Comment: That answer is not helpful for me.

Comment: @Epodax Not really though, this question combines checking string length and checking for the existence of a space.

Comment: So, don't want a limit on how many words / length but simply that people don't post gibberish? That's gonna be hard to check,  if it's because of the cosmetic then I believe some one all ready posted a answer to that.

Comment: @Epodax so you mean answer is not possible!!! :))) 
I give a try to that answers but not works for me that's why I come here to ask.

Comment: ..uh what? No, I said it's gonna be hard, not impossible, there's a few things that are actually impossible to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to use

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It will break the string when it gets too long

Comment: Your solution is good to handle this issue when displaying data on page.

Answer (score 2):

```
$post = $_POST['review'];
$postArray = explode(' ' , $post);
$flag=0;
foreach($postArray as $value)
{
    if(strlen($value)>45)  // the largest word has count 45 characters , you can change the count
         $flag = 1;
}

 if($flag)
    echo "word not allowed";
```

As the largest word is of 45 characters , so you can put a check like above  , but you can change the word length as their is less probability of user putting that word.

Comment: I got issue!! This is my input string: `hi this is review for testing` and I got error message: "word not allowed", why this because in input string no words have length more than 45 characters.

Comment: `<?php

$word = "hi this is review for testing";

$postArray = explode(' ' , $word);
$flag=0;
foreach($postArray as $value)
{
    if(strlen($value)>45)  // the largest word has count 45 characters , you can change the count
         $flag = 1;
}

 if($flag)
    echo "word not allowed";
 else
  echo "words are ok";

?>`  please check this , i dodn't got the error

Comment: In this case it is working fine but in case of actual post submission it is not working.

Comment: please paste the whole code so that i can see it . https://ideone.com/ , add the code here and share it will me so i can see

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following functions :

- [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strlen.php) to check the length of your string
- [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stristr.php) to check if there is a space

In the end, you should have something like this :

```
if (strlen($string) > $limit && stristr($string, ' ') === false) {
    // Don't store the string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can check or count total word to make a minimum sentence and also check the length

```
$string="Hello world!";
$count= str_word_count($string);
$arr = explode(' ',trim($string));
$len=strlen($arr[0]);
```

In Css you can view to use

word-wrap:break-word;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating your data, you can just wrap it on the UI layer using CSS. Use:

`word-wrap: break-word;`

For more info, see this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't know if you are using PHP, but the solution is quite simple:
Let's say you want a review to have maximum 100 length:

```
if (strlen($review)<100) {
 // post the review
}
else {
  die("Sorry the input is too large.");
}
```

Another way of doing it, **but it`s not safe**:

```
<input type="text" name="review" maxlength="100">
```

Hope it helps.