# How to display a text if the string length is grater than x amoung in php

Tags: php

i wants to display this text in a different div if the text character length is grater than 10 chars.

```
$tasdg = "cars";
if(strlen(($tasdg)>10)) {
    print ' <div style="font-size:22px; font-weight:bold;">'.$tasdg.'</div>';
}else {
    print '<div style="font-size:12px;">'.$tasdg.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: What is your problem???

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563152/check-string-length-in-php

Comment: i found a answer. Thanks all

Comment: @alex Before you post a question search for it, if don't found then ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your IF statement to look like this:

```
if(strlen($tasdg)>10) {
```

You placed the brackets wrong, the result of strlen($tagdg) needs to be more than 10.

Comment: You got the bug, add some information about the bug.